# Php shuffle through database users

Tags: php, random, shuffle

How can I shuffle through the users of my database, currently I have this:

```
$users = db->select($table, $columnUsers);

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user['firstname'];
}
```

This echo's me out all users of my database, but how can I shuffle those users at this point?

Comment: what did you tried so far? put the answer in your question!

Answer (score 0):

Use PHP's [Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) that shuffles the array containing users.

```
$users = db->select($table, $columnUsers);

shuffle($users);

foreach($users as $user) {
    echo $user['firstname'];
}
```

Comment: wouldn't be better to shuffle them in the Database layer?